# Where to store many subofolder locally images android

Tags: android, image, png, store, sd-card

I have a series of images (200-300) of animals that will be loaded inside my application.There is a root folder and subfolders containing 3-4 images to any type of animal. 
The application must work in local.Where I recommended to save these pictures? In assets or drawable directory ? Or something else ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store your images in drawable folder. 
You can create sub folders in assets dir. and call it with reference to the folder / dir structure. 
I'm not sure though you can do it with drawables or not as never tried it but you can give it a try. Rest follow the below arrays approach to manage your code better.
Plus if you want to categorize them then care different arrays for each category and put the resource reference in each one of them accordingly. Then you can user these category arrays according to your needs.

e.g

String dogs[] = {R.drawable.dog1, R.drawable.dog2, R.drawable.dog3, etc};
String cats[] = {R.drawable.cat1, R.drawable.cat2, R.drawable.cat3, etc};

and you can use these arrays in their own category.

Comment: No. Wrong advise. In this way subfolders will not be possible.

Comment: why not put subfolder and folder root images in asset directory? Are there disavantages with this way?

Comment: @greenapps - buddy I didnt say it will create sub folders. I just said it will help in categorization.

Comment: @superfox - I think you can create subfolders in assets folder for categorization too... I have used the same previously... wait updating my answer

Comment: @superfox - root project folder? whats the current issue you are facing?

Comment: @ShivamChopra like this structure defined in top comment
assets//
AnimalImages//
 type1/ type11.png type12.png type2/ type21.png type22.png

Comment: @superfox - yes you can do that :)

Comment: @superfox - If you think my answer helped. You can select it and upvote it please. Thanks